# How to do linear stability analysis on this system of ODEs?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stability, non-linear-systems, complex-systems, linearized-theory

I was trying to do linear stability analysis of spring pendulum. I arrived at the differential equations which describe the system. But I am unable to proceed to linear stability analysis. Is it possible to do linear stability analysis on 2nd order differential equations by finding eigen-values of Jacobian matrix? The equations are as below:

$$mr'' - m(L+r)(\theta')^2-mg\cos(\theta)+kr' = 0$$ and

$$(L+r)\theta''+2r'\theta'+g\sin(\theta)=0.$$

---

UPDATE : The fixed points are $(mg/k,0)$ and $(-mg/k,\pi)$

Comment: I'd start by linearizing the problem about a stationary point.  Then reorganize into a system of first order linear o.d.e.s, the eigenvalues of that matrix should be <1.

Comment: @user3823992 Don't you mean that the eigenvalues should have negative real part, since an eigenvalue $\lambda$ corresponds to an $\exp(\lambda\,t)$ term in the solution of the linearised DEs? ($|\lambda_j|<1$ is the criterion for discrete time systems, *i.e.* coupled recurrence relationships, since $\lambda_j$ then corresponds to a $\lambda_j^n$ term in the solution of linearised equations).

Comment: Yeah, quite right.  Negative real parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take the core of the question to be

> Is it possible to do linear stability analysis on 2nd order differential equations by finding eigen values of Jacobian matrix?

The answer is yes, but first you have to convert your second-order equations into first-order ones.

This is actually pretty easy to do: every time you see a second derivative, e.g. $x''$, you just introduce a new variable, $y=x'$. Then you can replace $x''$ with $y'$. The equation $x'=y$ should be added to the set of equations, so in your case your two second-order equations will become four first-order ones. Then after rearranging the equations to put all the derivatives on the left-hand side, you can write down the Jacobian and calculate its eigenvalues just as you would for any set of first-order differential equations.

(I apologise for not doing the work of actually applying this technique to your problem, but I hope this answer gives you enough information to do it yourself.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Nathaniel is clear and correct, yet let me add: it is obvious by inspection that this is motion in a potential, which can be derived from a Hamiltonian
$$
\frac{\dot r^2+ r^2\dot\theta^2}{2} + V(r,\theta)\;.
$$
All you need to do now is to establish whether, around the equilibrium points, $V$ has a minimum or a maximum/saddle: in the first case the motion is stable, otherwise not. This requires computing eigenvalues of a $2\times 2$ matrix, considerably easier than the $4\times 4$ matrix suggested by Nathaniel.

Also, it allows you to make some contact with physics, rather discussing it as a purely mathematical problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to linearize your equations around any stationary point. Then you can indeed treat it like by finding eigen values.